# How to inject IPrincipal into a class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0, userprincipal

I have a class where I need to access `IPrincipal` because I will save some user information in a database from that class.

To inject it, I added this in Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPrincipal>(
    (sp) => sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User
);
```

With that, I receive a warning about `IHttpContextAccessor` telling that I need to use it with caution because it relies on `AsyncLocal`, and second, other warnings are shown telling I need to dereference `GetService` and `HttpContext`.

How can I do that properly in .NET Core 6?

[image]

Comment: `IPrincipal` is runtime data. Prevent injecting runtime data into constructors of your components. Instead hide them behind an abstraction, as described [here](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: The comment in the documentation about "ambient state" is weird IMO. I can't see how it makes testing harder, as an important part of having interfaces is that they can be replaced for testing purposes. So while `HttpContextAccesser` certainly depends on `AsyncLocal` a fake implementation doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I receive a warning ... telling that I need to use it with caution because it relies

No, it is not the warning which is telling that, the caution comes from the remarks in the [interface documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#remarks) which you see when you mouse over the interface definition.

The warning you are getting is about dereferencing of a possibly null reference (some [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings)).

> warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference.

The issue is that `GetService` can return null,  and `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext` can be null also which is caught by compiler (see [nullable references types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)). The proper workaround would be to extract corresonding abstraction and register/resolve it:

```cs
public interface IPrincipalProvider
{
    IPrincipal? Principal { get; }
}

public class PrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public PrincipalProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public IPrincipal? Principal => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
}

builder.Services.AddScoped<IPrincipalProvider, PrincipalProvider>();
```

Comment: Or, optionally, you can put the `httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User` code inside the `Principal` property. This allows the `PrincipalProvider` to become stateless and allows it to be registered using `AddSingleton`. But nonetheless, you got my +1.